# Cool air comes in through the window

Tags: word-usage, usage

It's pretty cold outside, and someone has opened the window. (Car, or maybe a room).

> Close the window, it's pretty cold outside.

I know that this is one way to describe it. But is there a way to use "air"( that comes in through the window) in anyway in this context?

> Close the window, air's coming in. (through the window.)
>
> Close the window, cool air's coming in.

Is there a better way to put it?

And if it's windy:

> It's pretty windy outside, and air's coming inside.

I know that the last part night not be used in the last sentence, but I just want to know the best way to put "air" in the sentence.

Comment: There are so many ways to express this depending upon the precise circumstances.  All your suggestions are possible, although “air’s coming inside” sounds strange (as if the house has no air in it before that!). Your first suggestion is probably the best (most likely). The concept of “a draft” is one possibility you may be missing.

Comment: One idiomatic sentence I’d expect here is, “Shut the widow, its freezing.” This is usually deliberate exaggeration of course.

Answer (score -1):

```
Draft (noun) A current of air, usually coming into a room or vehicle.
```

It is almost always used when it's cold air, so that would fit perfectly.

"please close the window, there's a draft"

Comment: So my sentences don't sound natural, right? I mean they aren't likely to be used, right? And is "draft" commonly used in this context?

Comment: “...there is a draft” will work in context but is not necessarily better than the first sentence “...it’s pretty cold outside.”  A draft is a breeze generated through a house etc. typically when windows (or other gaps) allow for a flow of air. An open window on a cold still day often doesn’t cause a draft but may be undesirable in terms of cooling down the room.